# ASP.NET RouteConfig dynamic entry off Root

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have statically mapped all controllers except one ... a `LookupController` that I would like to operate off root.

Here are my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Root",
    url: "",
    defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "home/{action}/{id}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "User",
    url: "user/{action}/{id}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Company",
    url: "company/{action}/{id}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Recruiter",
    url: "recruiter/{action}/{id}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Lookup",
    url: "{company}/{recruiter}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Lookup", action = "Index" }
);
```

Everything works fine EXCEPT the last entry for `Lookup`.

This breaks everything, including the other routes.

Basically, I want my URLs to be:

```
/Home
/User
/Company
/Recruiter
/{company}/{recruiter}
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Thank you very much in advanced!

**EDIT:** Adding LookupController by request:

```
public class LookupController : Controller
{
    private RecruiterSightContext db = new RecruiterSightContext();

    // GET: Lookup
    public ActionResult Index(string company, string recruiter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(company) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(recruiter))
        {
            TempData["errorMessage"] = "No Company or Recruiter specified in URL";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        // Company lookup
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(recruiter))
        {
            Company foundCompany = db.Companies.FirstOrDefault(c => company.ToLower().Equals(c.Slug.ToLower()));
            if (foundCompany == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Display", "Company", new {companyId = foundCompany.CompanyId});
        }

        Recruiter foundRecruiter = db.Recruiters.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Slug.ToLower().Equals(recruiter.ToLower()));
        if (foundRecruiter == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("RecruiterView", "Recruiter", new {recruiterId = foundRecruiter.RecruiterId});
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _operate off root_?

Comment: Instead of having the Controller name like `/Home`, I just want to have the parameters off root, ex: `/{company}/{recruiter}` and route those 2 parameters to my `LookupController`

Comment: OK - your also had a route named "Root" :) How are you calling that method and how is it _breaking_?

Comment: "Root" is there so if there is no parameters, just a call to /, it will return my index page.  If there are any parameters, I want to send those to the LookupController.

Comment: Yes, but what problems are you having? What is _breaking_? If you generate a route with 2 segments (and it does not match one of the above routes (and I assume you actually do have `defaults: new { ... }` on them) then it will be hit. But the code in your method is checking if one or the other is `null` which does not make sense since it will only be called if  your provide both

Answer (score 0):

If your `Lookup` folder exists:

try to change:

**from:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Lookup",
    url: "{company}/{recruiter}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Lookup", action = "Index" }
);
```

**to:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Lookup",
    url: "company/recruiter",
    defaults: new { controller = "Lookup", action = "Index" }
);
```

then in your `Browser`

Add like this:

```
company/recruiter
```

If your Lookup is different of index then i think you need to create another function that calling your Lookup like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Lookup",
    url: "company/recruiter",
    defaults: new { controller = "Lookup", action = "LookupWithParameter" }

);
```

then in your Controller:

```
public ActionResult LookupWithParameter(String Company, string recruiter)
```

And don't forget to create another `.cshtml` file to redirect the page of your Lookup which is located at your `Lookup folder`

**Here's the scenario:**

Assuming that you are currently working at your `Index.cshtml` page which in your `Home` Controller then you want to redirect into Lookup page.

Index(Home) .cshtml file:

```
<div id="content">
        @{
            if (IsPost) { 
            <!--this option if you don't need to change another page-->
            string company = Request["Company"]; 
            string recruiter = Request["Recruiter"]; 
            <p>You entered: <br />
            Company Name: @company <br />
            Recruiter Name: @recruiter</p>


            }
            else
            {
            <form method="post" action="company/recruiter">
            Company Name:<br />
            <input type="text" name="Company" value="" id="idcompany" /><br />
            Contact Name:<br />
            <input type="text" name="Recruiter" value=""id="idrecruiter" /><br /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
            </form>
             }
       } 
    </div>
```

**LookupController:**

```
   public class LookupController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Lookup/

        public ActionResult MyLookup(string Company, string Recruiter)
        {
            // this is how to pass the value of parameter company and recruiter input from index.
            //Your Action here and you can use to Debug while runnning notice that the company and the recruiter has a content from index home input
            return View();
        }

    }
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "Lookup",
                       url: "company/recruiter",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Lookup", action = "MyLookup" }
                   );
```

Make sure that you have a `Lookup` folder that contains `MyLookup.cshtml`

Comment: But I need the Company and Recruiter to be dynamic variables, basically I need the LookupController to get Company: Veredus and Recruiter: Fred as parameters.

Comment: Hows your `Lookup Controller` look like? You are pointing the index function of your Controller. `action = "Index"`. It seems your index will look like this `public ActionResult index(String Company, string recruiter)`

Comment: I added it to the original question.

Comment: It is running and tested.. Good Luck